# How to finalize MAMP Wordpress conversion

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, wamp, mamp

I have followed just about every tutorial to bring my live wordpress site to a local server. One of the most thorough being [THIS ONE](https://www.webnots.com/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-localhost/).

I can get my entire site to run except for the home page, and wp-admin control panel. The home page only shows half of the page, and when I try to login to the control panel, it says,

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

In other words, I know that I am connected to the correct database and most of the content is loaded, but there is still something missing.

The SQL Queries I run are as follows:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value=replace(option_value, 'http://example.com','http://localhost:8888/mynewexample')
WHERE option_name='home' OR option_name='siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=replace(post_content,'http://example.com','http://localhost:8888/mynewexample');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=replace(meta_value,'http://example.com','http://localhost:8888/mynewexample');
```

I have additionally configured the wp-config file as directed.

My site files are located in a /Sites folder on my local disk, as configured in MAMP.

The PHP and Apache error logs are [linked HERE.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5am0at736oml9v/Error%20Logs.zip?dl=0)

Can anyone pinpoint a problem, or direct me to a source where I can receive live help? Much Appreciated!

Comment: What's in the error log? Have you enabled `display_errors` and setup `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`?

Comment: I believe the error reporting is configured. I have added a link to the error logs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your error log has the answer, you should always look there first if you experience any problems, in most cases the solution can be found by simply using your favorite search engine and searching for the error message in the log file.

In fact: always make sure that it doesn't contain any PHP errors, even if you don't see problems, they might be lurking in the dark, waiting for the right moment to pounce and ruin your day.

With that out of the way, here's we go

> [04-Nov-2017 11:37:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: []
>   operator not supported for strings in
>   /Users/graham/Sites/po/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php:71

That's happening because of your PHP version. Apparently the theme authors either do not support your version or haven't tested with your version. You should report a bug to them (if you are on the latest version of the plugin; if you are not, update and report a bug if the problem persists).

In the meantime, you can fix it temporarily by replacing `[]` with `array()` in that line of that file (and any other occurrence that might be there).